# What formula should I use to determine a row from data entry number? (OFFSET also)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is the data I am working with;

[image: Image Example]

- `A1:A10` is my example range to search for the entered "16"
- How do I determine the row data entry #16 is in?
- Then how do I offset from the
  newly determined row, 1 column to the right, for determining `B12,C12,D12,E12,F12`?

As a possible solution I have come up with 
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(A12,A1:A10)),0,1)
for B12 and C12 just modifying the offset ..)),0,2) for the other values.

Comment: VLOOKUP() or INDEX/MATCH

Comment: Use `MATCH()` to find the row and then use `INDEX()` to retrieve the associated items.

Comment: @garys-student I ended up using =OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(A12,A1:A10)),0,1) in B12 and adjusting the column offset for 1 over each time.

Answer (score 1):

Using VLOOKUP (the simplest way to do it):

```
=VLOOKUP($A$12,$A$1:$F$10,COLUMN(B12),FALSE)
```

Type it on cell B12 and then just copy and paste it on the range C12:F12.
The COLUMN() function automatically chooses the column, so you don't need to input it on every cell.
The $ symbol is necessary when copying, to maintain the absolute reference on the function.

Comment: Good answer. Keep in mind, depending on the region the OP is in, they may have to use commas (`,`) in place of semicolon (`;`).

Comment: That is right. Already changed that. I always have a little trouble finding all those nuances, since my version is in portuguese. Thanks.